# Calendar Syncronization in Android Application

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am working on project a in which i have to sync my program with google `Calendar` using Android application.

for that i am using `eclipse` and i got some code online but i dont know wht .jar file i need to add for support below importss..

```
import com.google.Android.gdata.client.AndroidXmlParserFactory;

import com.google.Android.gdata.client.JakartaGDataClient;

import com.google.wireless.gdata.calendar.client.CalendarClient;

import com.google.wireless.gdata.calendar.data.EventEntry;

import com.google.wireless.gdata.calendar.data.When;

import com.google.wireless.gdata.calendar.parser.xml.XmlCalendarGDataParserFactory;

import com.google.wireless.gdata.client.QueryParams;

import com.google.wireless.gdata.data.Feed;

import com.google.wireless.gdata.parser.GDataParser;
```

please can anybody help me regarding this ..

or any other clue for my project because i got a deadline on next week ..

thank you very much in advance..

i'll really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

com.google.android.gdata and com.google.wireless are not part of the public SDK so you won't be able to use them.

I haven't tried to use the gdata-java-client library on android yet, but you should see if you can download it and include it in your project and see if you can compile and run it on android.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/